# How to get the upsell product Collection in list page in magento 2

Tags: collection, magento2.2.2, category-listing, up-sells

I have created a module to show upsell products in List page.
In List page, I have put one icon on each product, while clicking that icon, It would need to show upsell products list which is associated with the current product.
So Please provide me a solution to get the upsell products list Collection, for a particular product in list page.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. I won't recommend using objectManager. Instead create function and call your Upsell products on List Page.

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$current_id = 10; //get current product id. Its should be dynamic each time you click
$current_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($current_id);

if ($current_product) {
    $upSellProducts = $current_product->getUpSellProducts();
    if (!empty($upSellProducts)) {
        foreach ($upSellProducts as $upSellProduct) {
            $productId = $upSellProduct->getId();
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); 
            echo $product->getName().'<br />';
            echo $product->getSku().'<br />';
            echo $product->getProductUrl().'<br />';
            echo $product->getImage().'<br />';        
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How to get price and rating collection for upsell products

Comment: Hi @Abishek, as per above code ,i wish to get only the instock upsell product collection like in view page

Comment: Do you want to get only in stock upsell products?

Comment: Yes , like in view page

Comment: I wish to add stock filter while getting the collection instead of foreach the all the upsell products and check stock status

Comment: I am showing a custom upsell product icon in list page , it should  be visible if the upsell products (in-stock) are available for the current product

Comment: I don't think so you can do it without foreach loop. you can break the loop after 4 products.

Comment: Then in default magento, how they display upsell products in view page

Comment: check out the list.phtml file for upsell products

Comment: Yes i have checked, they simply got the collection like $block->getItemCollections->getItems from core block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78853/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-sri).